# Does $f:X \longrightarrow Y$ open, continuous and surjective preserve being $T_0$?

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

I am asked to prove or disprove that if $X$ is $T_0$ and $f: X \longrightarrow Y$ is continuous, open and surjective then $Y$ is also $T_0$.

At first I tried to find any counterexample but I didn't find any. So I tried to prove it.

My attempt was that if $y_1 , y_2 \in Y$ are different points then by $f$ being surjective $f^{-1}(\{y_1\}) , f^{-1}(\{y_2\})$ are both non empty.
If there exists $x \in f^{-1}(\{y_1\})$ with a neighbourhood $V$ of $x$ that has no points in common with $f^{-1}(\{y_2\})$ then $f(V)$ is a neighbourhood that contains $y_1$ but not $y_2$. Analogously, if there exists $x \in f^{-1}(\{y_2\})$ with a neighbourhood that contains no points of $f^{-1}(\{y_1\})$ then the same holds.

So if those points doesn't exist, that means that $f^{-1}(\{y_2\})\subseteq \overline{f^{-1}(\{y_1\})}$ and $f^{-1}(\{y_1\}) \subseteq \overline{f^{-1}(\{y_2\})}$. I think this may contradict that $X$ is $T_0$ but I am struggling to prove it (if it's true). Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Proving this will be impossible. Hint: Consider spaces $Y=X/\sim$ where $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on $X,$ and $Y$ is given the quotient topology. Find a messy $\sim.$

Comment: Mind, all quotient maps are continuous and surjective, but not all quotient maps are open, but if you pick $\sim$ carefully, you'll get an open map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're struggling because the claim is not true.  An elementary example is as follows:

let $X=(\mathbb{Z};\text{cofinite})$ (that is, $S\subseteq X$ is open iff $S$ is empty or $X\setminus S$ is finite) and $Y=(\mathbb{Z}/(2);\text{indiscrete})$.  Choose $f$ to be the quotient map (in the algebraic sense) which sends every $n$ to its remainder modulo $2$.

As a quotient of rings, $f$ must be surjective; since the indiscrete topology is terminal, $f$ must be continuous; and the image of every nonempty open set is all of $\mathbb{Z}/(2)$, so that $f$ is open.  (All of these are also easy to check "by hand".)

But $X$ is $T_0$ and $Y$ is not.

Comment: +1. More generally let $X$ be any non-empty $T_0$ space with a dense, co-dense subset $D.$ Let $f(x)=1$ if $x\in D$ and $f(x)=0$ if $x\in X$ \ $D.$